Why acceleration is not always parallel to velocity but velocity is always parallel to displacement?
Velocity is derivative of displacement :
$$\vec v=\frac{\mathrm {d\vec r}}{\mathrm dt}$$
And acceleration is derivative of velocity.
$$\vec a=\frac{\mathrm {d\vec v}}{\mathrm dt}$$
Given that their definitions looks very similar, why is it the case that acceleration is not always parallel to velocity but velocity is always parallel to displacement ?
My teacher told me that I'll learn about it in higher classes due to high level mathematics. So, I'm looking for an intuitive answer if possible.

It's also true that average velocity over a time period  is equal to the total displacement over that time period.

Velocity is not the derivative of displacement.  Rather, it is the derivative of the position vector $r$.  The displacement would be something like $dr$.  Of course, the velocity is not parallel to the position vector.  For example, when a particle moves along the unit circle, the velocity will always be perpendicular to the position vector.
A similar analysis applies to the acceleration.  It will be parallel to the change $dv$ in the tangent vector.  There is nothing "high level" about this.

Oops , sorry about it.

I got confused by position vector and displacement vector.

Happens to the best of us!  No reason to be discouraged.
